# Impact of "kernel: Clocksource tsc unstable" on a GUI application

Tags: java, opengl, clock

I have this Java GUI application which uses OpenGL and Eclipse RCP + SWT running on a Linux (Fedora 7) machine equipped with Pentium P or Core 2 Duo CPU. It supposed to run and accept user input for months.

After a few weeks of running the whole interface freezes without reason. Mouse is very slow and keyboard stops responding shortly. I have eliminated all possible resource leaks (not disposed graphical objects, too many threads etc). I can see in my log files that my application threads are running slowly for less than one minute but then they recover their normal pace (the thread running the GUI as well).

But the GUI itself remains blocked... In my OS log file I see something like this
'kernel: Clocksource tsc unstable'. Could this be related to my problem?